# Year on x-axis is pinned to January on Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, x-axis

I have a dataframe as follows.
| Date| A | B |
|-- | ---- | -- |
| Jan-20| 205.0| 232.0
| Feb-20| 328.0 | 338.0

I turn the Date column into a datetime object, set it as the index and graph it.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format="%b-%y") 
df = df.set_index("Date")
df.plot(kind='line', figsize=(10,5), color=["#FDCE0D","#3A424A"])
```

However I get the following x-axis where the year is under each instance of January.
[image]

Is there a way to have the year go next to each month, such as 'Jan 2018'? I know I can perform a
`.strftime("%b %Y)` but I want to keep it as a datetime object as I'm overlaying shading to the graph using datetime ranges.

When I try to format it the following way I get this.

```
date_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b %Y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_fmt)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you assign your plot to a variable (ax), you can do the following.

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax.set_xticks(df.index)
date_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b %Y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_fmt)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work, it messes up the dates by setting it to 1971. It's also strange that I have July 1971 twice now.

Comment: Try adding ax.set_xticks(df.index) before the code above.

Comment: Just noticed this question was closed. The link provided has a very comprehensive answer.